# Taskbar icon won't show when I have a fade in feature in my form

Tags: vb.net, taskbar

I've created a notification bar on a form and basically have it exactly how I need it... Except, when I put a fade in feature, the taskbar icon doesn't show up. To my application, it's necessary, because the taskbar icon flashes orange when a notification is shown. I've checked the obvious such as: my `ShowInTaskbar` property = true, and the correct icon is selected in the application properties.

I wanted to know if anyone knows why this would happen, and if there is a way around this where I can keep the fade in effect of the form.

I've included the form code. It's lines 13, 20 and 27-31 that activate the fade in.

```
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports system.runtime.interopservices

public class form10

<DllImport("user32.dll", EntryPoint:="FlashWindow")>
Public Shared Function FlashWindow(ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal bInvert As Integer) As Integer
End Function

Private Sub Form10_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    ' sets form to bottom right of page 
    Me.Location = New Point(Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Width - 381, Screen.PrimaryScreen.WorkingArea.Height - 131)
    Me.Opacity = 0.1

    With Timer1
        .Interval = 300
        .Enabled = True
        .Start()
    End With

    Timer2.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    FlashWindow(Me.Handle, 1)
End Sub

Private Sub Timer2_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer2.Tick
    If Me.Opacity < 1.0 Then
        Me.Opacity = Me.Opacity + 0.1
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code works fine for me (taskbar icon is visible and flashing) on Windows 7 x64

Comment: After further tests it decides to work under certain conditions. for instance if it isn't the `topmost` it will work, or if you drag it about it will work. Not sure how to get it to flash regardless. @Verdolino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed it by stopping the timer and adding this code to the Private sub Timer2_Tick

```
If Me.Opacity = 1 Then Timer2.Stop() End If
```

Also taking off the `TopMost` property and adding `me.TopMost = True` code to the load sub fully corrected my issue.